# What benefits for more EKG leads?

Tags: heart, electrocardiogram

It seems that the 12-lead EKG is the gold standard for diagnosing many heart problems, but they're limited to fairly short samples (e.g. 30 minutes). Its possible to send a patient home for several days to be monitored with a 3-lead Holter Monitor, or a Zio patch, which clearly does better at detecting transient heart issues, but is limited by the number of leads (?).

Putting aside the additional differences in the monitoring period, what might you hope to be able to diagnose with a 12 lead EKG vs, the single or 3 lead ambulatory monitors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Holters and Zios are great for long-term monitoring, the 12-lead ECG can give information that is more specific to the anatomical regions of the heart.
The leads are grouped as follows:

- II, III, aVF—Inferior
- V1-V2—Septal
- V3-V4—Anterior
- I, aVL, V5-V6—Lateral
- aVR—Not really in any "category", but it is a right-sided lead.

One clear example of where this is useful is for localizing ST elevated myocardial infarction. If a patient presents with ST elevations in leads II, III, and aVF with reciprocal ST depressions in some of the anterior or lateral leads, it is evident that the patient is experiencing an inferior infarct, likely due to ischemic obstruction of the right coronary artery.

From an electrophysiological perspective, the additional leads can help to localize foci of arrythmias. Think of it as a triangulation system, where with increased number of leads, we get more specific information about each area of the heart. Analyzing the waveforms in a specific leads can dictate whether the depolarization is originating from the respective regions (negative waveform, traveling away from that lead), or from the opposing region (positive waveform, traveling towards that lead). Using this technique in several leads of one ECG can help to zone in on the culprit area. Again, think triangulation.

Holters are great, Zios are great, inpatient telemetry monitoring is great too, but none of these give the same amount of information you can glean from a 12-lead.

References:
Burns, E., Buttner, R., & Buttner, E. B. and R. (2023, June 8). Anterior myocardial infarction. Life in the Fast Lane • LITFL. https://litfl.com/anterior-myocardial-infarction-ecg-library/

Enriquez, A., Baranchuk, A., Briceno, D., Saenz, L., & Garcia, F. (2019). How to use the 12-lead ECG to predict the site of origin of idiopathic ventricular arrhythmias. Heart Rhythm, 16(10), 1538–1544. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.hrthm.2019.04.002